# Unable to download Ubuntu ISO

Tags: 20.04

Why am I not able to download Ubuntu again on my system? Whenever I try to download, it shows that "The requested URL was not found on this server."

[image: Screenshot of the problem occurred during download]

Comment: That is not the official Ubuntu download site.

Comment: Hey Prakash Santra! I welcome you to Ask Ubuntu! I suggest you to go through the [tour] page. If you have any doubts about Ask Ubuntu, you can read the help center articles here: https://askubuntu.com/help

Answer (score 2):

Please try a different link.

[This is the official link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

And the link for the ISO of Ubuntu 20.04.2 is https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso